# Nodejs fails to bootstrap process due to heap size

Tags: node.js, heap-memory

I'm initiating a nodejs process with command:

```
node --max_old_space_size=8192 helloworld.js
```

But it fails to bootstrap and output this Javascript heap out of memory error:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[10464:04067CC8]   276580 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 1473.3 (1542.1) -> 1071.8 (1466.5) MB, 866.8 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.955, current mu = 0.832) last resort GC in old space requested
[10464:04067CC8]   277977 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 1071.8 (1454.5) -> 1066.0 (1334.8) MB, 1397.6 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.867, current mu = 0.000) last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

1. If I change `8192` to `4092` then it successed.
2. The error **immediately** outputs.
3. This previously worked! Just returned from a long time and now this happens.

So looks like Node is just fail to allocating `8192` to my process. WHY?!

Answer (score 0):

**Reinstalling NodeJs** worked and I don't see this error anymore.